# Datasource error when migrating from Tomcat server to JBoss?

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

I would appreciate if anyone can help me out here. I have developed an application using Apache Tomcat and it is deployed and working. However when I wanted to migrate the app to JBoss and deploy the WAR file on that server, I got a datasource error. I'm new to JBoss and I have no clue on what should I do next to solve this issue. I would appreciate if someone could guide me through this process!

My DBConnector class code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory;
```

public class DbConnector {

```
private static String JDBC_DRIVER = "jdbc.driver";
private static String JDBC_URL = "jdbc.url";
private static String JDBC_USER = "jdbc.user";
private static String JDBC_PASSWORD = "jdbc.password";
private static Properties props = new Properties();
private Connection connection = null;
private Statement stat = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;
private static volatile DataSource dsObj;
static {
    try {
        // a way to retrieve the data in
        // connection.properties found
        // in WEB-INF/classes
        InputStream is = DbConnector.class.getResourceAsStream("/connection.properties");
        props.load(is);
        //PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Class.forName(props.getProperty(JDBC_DRIVER)).newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void initialize() {
    try {
        dsObj = BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(props);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public DbConnector() {
    try {
        initialize();
        this.connection = getConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns DB Connection
 * @return Connection
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public static Connection getConnectionFromPool() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = null;
    // checking for null singleton instance
    if (null == dsObj) { // synchronized over class to make thread safe
        synchronized (DbConnector.class) {
    // double checking for making singleton instance thread safe
            if (null == dsObj) {
                initialize();
            }
        }
    }
    // getting connection from data sourceconnection = dsObj.getConnection();
    return connection;
}

/**
 * Get Connection
 * @return Connection object
 * @throws SQLException
 */
private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection(props.getProperty(JDBC_URL), props.getProperty(JDBC_USER), props.getProperty(JDBC_PASSWORD));
}

/**
 * Execute Query
 * Purpose: SELECT
 * @param sql SQL Statement
 * @return ResultSet
 */
public ResultSet executeQuery(String sql) {
    try {
        if (connection == null) {
            return null;
        }
        stat = connection.createStatement();
        rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);
        return rs;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Execute Update
 * Purpose: Insert, Update, Delete
 * @param sql SQL Statement
 * @return int No. of Rows Updated
 */
public int executeUpdate(String sql) {
    try {
        if (connection == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        stat = connection.createStatement();
        return stat.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();

        return -1;
    }
}

/**
 * Execute
 * Purpose: Create, Drop
 * @param sql statement to update.
 * @return true is statement execute sucessfuly and false otherwise
 */
public boolean execute(String sql) {
    try {
        if (connection == null) {
            return false;
        }
        stat = connection.createStatement();
        return stat.execute(sql);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();

        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Close ResultSet
 */
public void closeResultSet() {
    if (rs != null) {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}

/**
 * Close Statement
 */
public void closeStatement() {
    if (stat != null) {
        try {
            stat.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //log.error(e);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Close Connection
 */
public void closeConnection() {
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Close
 * Connection, Statement and Resultset     *
 */
public void close() {
    try {
        if (rs != null) {
            rs.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (stat != null) {
            stat.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

After reading about this online, I know I have to do something to the context.xml and web.xml files.

Would someone show me some sample code or give me some assistance with this please?

Comment: Remove the resource-ref in web.xml and post the stacktrace. You are mixing too many things.

Comment: Hi, Reposted plz help to solve

Comment: What is JBoss? JBoss Web? JBoss AS? JBoss Portal? JBoss Hibernate? And what version of it?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I do is get rid of your own connection pool code and use the one [provided by the container](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigDataSources). You basically define the DataSource and the container (Tomcat/JBOSS) will make it available to your application via JNDI. Once defined, you can refer to it in your web.xml. Search google for how-to.

```
<resource-ref>  
  <description>Customer Database</description>  
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/CustomerDB</res-ref-name>  
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>  
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>  
</resource-ref>
```

**UPDATE**

If you still want to make this work your way, then make sure you have the jar file containing the `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory` in your classpath (WEB-INF/lib). And post the stacktrace you are getting.

**UPDATE 2**

The error is very clear

***Web mapping already exists*** for deployment URL file:/C:/Users/Dane/Desktop/jboss-as-distribution-6.0.0.Final/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/tmp/vfs/automountec9d6360903186ac/SurveyApplication.war-a018e9cb945f462b/

Seems like you already have another application deployed with the same context path.

Comment: HI, unfortunately I don't have much time. Is there a faster way such that I only do changes to context and web.xml and minimum changes to my DBConnector class. Seek your help and understanding